# google-code-prettify seems dead

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

The [code formating engine](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) used by SO (google-code-prettify) seems [dead](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/list) (lasts two commits have been made on sep 2013 & mar 2014). As stated [on this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), each code-formatting request have to be redirected to this project.

In my case, I was wondering if C# `async`/`await` keywords highlighting could be improved on SO, but [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=265) is opened since 2 years......

Even if similar question have [already been asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126608/why-doesnt-stackoverflow-use-highlight-js-instead-of-google-code-prettify), I'm not talking about choosing the better framework over another. IMO, the problem is about future language support and new language features (like the "new" C# `async`/`await`).

Since this project is dead, shouldn't SE/SO take it in consideration and either replace google-code-prettify by another alternative, or make the SE dev-team collaborate on this project or fork it to resuscitate it and make things happens ?

Comment: Google Code is dead as well...

Comment: Good observation. It looks like one-man-show project ran by Mike Samuel and his priorities might have changed. You can certainly contribute or even take over the ownership responsibilities. It's open source anyway. @DeerHunter yes, all active Google Code projects should move to GitHub till [August 2015](http://betanews.com/2015/03/12/time-to-migrate-to-github-as-google-code-closes/)

Comment: There's also the lack of syntax highlighting for VimScript, especially the vi.SE site could benefit a lot from that. I wanted to code this last week, but after seeing the lack of activity decided it wasn't worth it ... I'm not sure if actually switching to another highlight engine is the best way to go ("don't fix what ain't broke"), but perhaps a SE fork might be worth considering?

Comment: [code-prettify is no longer dead.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264356/update-code-prettify)

Comment: Looks pretty near death to me.

Comment: `code-prettify` is certainly dead. Many languages are missing, and completed pull requests are sitting around for years with no approvals.

Comment: Looks like highlight.js is now used, refer to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) for details.

Answer (score 5):

We've officially switched to [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) network-wide. See the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353983/395497) for more details.