# YAML highlighting doesn't work on StackExchange sites but is supported by Google Prettify

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

When I comment a code-block with `<!-- language: lang-yaml -->` the page is generated with the right css-class `lang-yaml` but it has no effect. There is no syntax highlighting for YAML.

Example:

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
                algorithm: bcrypt
                cost: 12
            BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Administrateur:
                 algorithm: bcrypt
            BackOfficeBundle\Entity\Collaborateur:
                 algorithm: bcrypt
```

As described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) YAML **is in** the supported list (as an extension). Maybe extensions aren't loaded by default?

But if you look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109) YAML **is not in** the supported list. YAML is already supported by Google Prettify: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-yaml.js.

Comment: YAML is not on the supported list [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100)

Comment: @rene Ok. "_If a language that could be applied to a tag is already on the list, please raise a feature request here on Meta to have it deployed on the network._" Now I need to modify my question so it would be more like feature-request than bug or I can leave it as is?

Comment: Someone look at this, please, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Two years later and no fix.

Comment: Could we please have some decision on this? Either fix it/schedule for fixing, or tell us it's a won't fix.

Comment: @sorin, after 5 years, it was already fixed 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have added the syntax highlighting logic for YAML. It is now live (as you can see above).

Comment: Hooray! Hooray! Oh happy day!

Comment: Yaaay! (5 years later, but...yaaaay!) :)